# Refining search with ransack gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mobile, ransack

I'm building a mobile-friendly search, and need to have Ransack gem concatenate search parameters, such that a "tap" on a phone (or in a web browser "click") searches first for the day of the week with the first click, then adds the city with the second click, then adds any search terms or codes, etc.  Right now it searches one of the 4, but it won't let the user search more than one without actually typing in the box

WITHOUT using JavaScript, is there anything I can do to make these searches concatenate via "click" alone?  (that is, make the search boxes for "city" and "day" invisible?)  Some things I thought of, messed with, and couldn't get to work:
- prevent the search form from "clearing" and searching each parameter from "root" uniquely?
- add a && to iteratively add search functions (use &commit=Search at the end?)

Yes, I've read up on the ransack documentation, researched this extensively, tried many things, but nothing is working thus far.  My intuition tells me sense there's something I can do like. . .

`<%= f.text_field :city_cont, placeholder: "Add City", @q.day_cont(params[:city_cont]) %>`

in `index.html.erb`

or maybe it's some kind of variation on this:

`<%#= search_form_for @q, :url => request.fullpath, :method => :get, :html => { :class => 'form-search' } do |f| %>`

Donating this entire project to a 501(c)(3) and don't have a lot of time to mess with it; just want to get it done.

Any help/insight greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript filtering is the ideal solution here, but if you're set on doing full page refresh for each click, and then have the clicked item "persist" for future clicks, then you have to insert the current search parameters into the links for all clicks. The `params` hash will help, maybe a helper like:

```
link_to LABEL, with_params_for(CODE, VALUE)
```

AND

```
def with_params_for(code, value)
  current_params = params["q"].except(code)
  "/meetings?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q[#{code}]=#{value}&commit=Search&" +
    current_params.map { |cp| "q[#{cp}]=#{params['q'][cp]}" }.join("&")
end
```

Comment: The code above added to app/helpers/meetings_helper.rb.  But I am not sure about the correct syntax for this part

`link_to LABEL, with_params_for(CODE, VALUE)`

Line 25 from meetings/index.html.erb I've tried: 

`<%= link_to "Campbell", with_params_for(city_cont: camp)%></li>    `

` ... (:city_cont, camp)%>`
` ... ([city_cont], camp)%>`
` ... (city_cont:camp)%>`
` ... ([city_cont]=camp)%>`      Nothing is working!

Comment: This would depend on other things, but try `<%= link_to "Campbell", with_params_for("city_cont", "camp")%></li>`

Comment: `NoMethodError in Meetings#index`

Showing aasj/app/views/meetings/index.html.erb where line #25 raised:

`undefined method `except' for nil:NilClass`

Extracted source (around line #25):
  
`25:     <li><%= link_to "Campbell", with_params_for("city_cont", "camp")%></li>`                                                          So Trying to understand what this means; line #3 in the helper is set to `current_params = params["q"].except(code)` which means that something to do with the `params` object is not getting set correctly?